# Excel File is getting corrupted when Creating a excel file in temp folder using jar file

Tags: java, excel, jar

I have created a jar file which will create a excel file in temp folder by using inputStream of excel file present inside jar file. I have 2 excel files. One excel file with size of 35kb with 2 sheets and Another excel file size with 53kb with 3 sheets. When I'm running with Eclipse, file is creating in temp folder without any issue but when I do the same using jar file. File with 53Kb size is getting corrupted. Is someone have any idea on this,

***Code Snippet***

```
InputStream is=Test.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("New_User_Datasheet.xls");
```

***File Creation Snippet***

```
public File createFile(InputStream inStream, String fileName, String fileExtn) throws IOException {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[inStream.available()];
         inStream.read(buffer);
        if (!(new File(String.valueOf(System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir")) + "\\Resources")).exists()) {
             File tempFile = new File(
                    String.valueOf(System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir")) + "\\Resources");
                tempFile.mkdir();
                try {
                 Thread.sleep(1000L);
                 } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                     e.printStackTrace();
                 }
         }
         String file = "";
            try {
                File Parent = new File(
                    String.valueOf(System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir")) + "\\Resources");
                File temp = new File(Parent, String.valueOf(fileName) + fileExtn);
                if (temp.exists())
                    temp.delete();
                temp.createNewFile();
             Thread.sleep(1000L);
             file = temp.getAbsolutePath();
             Files.write(buffer, temp);
             } catch (Exception e) 
            {
                 e.printStackTrace();
             }
            return new File(file);
         }
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution in Google, I have written InputStream as OutputStream instead of BufferReader.

***Code Snippet***

```
 OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream("/Users/pankaj/new_source.txt");
            
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            int bytesRead;
            //read from is to buffer
            while((bytesRead = is.read(buffer)) !=-1){
                os.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
            }
            is.close();
            //flush OutputStream to write any buffered data to file
            os.flush();
            os.close();
```